# Rails 4: Have form load with file already present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, file, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a file upload form that I would like to have a default file already loaded when the page loads.  In other words, one of the params is the temp file's path, and I'd like that file to be the default file in the form.

```
<!-- params[:checked_file] is a path to the desired file -->
<div class="content">
    <%= form_tag import_timecard_path, multipart: true do %>
      <!-- this doesn't load the file -->
        <%= file_field :file, params[:checked_file], class: "btn" %>
        <%= collection_select :timecard, :payroll_id, Payroll.all, :id, :dates %>
        <%= submit_tag "Import", class: "btn btn-primary btn-raised" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a default value for the file field due security reasons. Only user can fill that field.

However you can show the preview of the 'default' file. 
Consider the following:
(Assuming `@file` is your preloaded file)

```
<% if @file.exists? %>
  <p class="small">
    Default:
  </p>
  <%= @file.name =>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :file, @file %>
<% end %>

<%= file_field_tag :file %>
```

You can use the hidden field for storing preloaded file. If user uploads his own file, hidden field value will be overriden.

If you save the filepath to DB, you can set the default filepath with migration and omit the hidden field:

```
t.string :filepath, default: <path_to_temp_file>
```